# unable to hide/show div tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to hide or show my div tag based on the selection of a value from my dropdown. There are 2 values in the dropdown, select the value `1` will hide the div, selecting the other will show the div. But it is not working, my div tag is always invisible.  Please help me, thanks in advance.
Please see the sample code:

```
@if (Model.Selectedtype == 3)
                                    {
                                        <div id="testDiv" class="form-group col-md-3">
        
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.testvalue, new { @class = "col-form-label col-form-label-sm text-primary" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.testvalue, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm selectpicker show-tick", data_live_search = true, title = "Select an option", data_icon_base = "fa", data_tick_icon = "fa-check" } })
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    }
    
    function incidentChangeHandler(e) {
                var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text().toLowerCase();
                var elem = $(this).parent();
                var selectedValue = e.target.value;
                
                
                if (selectedValue === '3') {
                    alert("entered");
                    $('#testDiv').addClass('d - none');
                } else {
                    alert("else");
                    $('#testDiv').removeClass('d-none');
                }
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question with the *rendered* HTML, not the Razor code.   Please also include:  what is `selectedValue` (how and *when* do you get this value).   Is `'d - none'` a typo in the question?  Or is that your actual code?   Ideally, create a snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) the demonstrates the issue.   Finally, provide details on what "not working" means - does your `select` `change` event fire?  Is `selectedValue` the correct value?  Does your `#testDiv'` have the class `d-none` or is it hidden some other way.   There's too much to speculate on here.

Comment: selected value is the dropdown value, i have put alert messages in to see if my logic is going in right direction.  so when 3 is selected, testdiv should be shown , else it should be hidden,  sorry, 'd - none' is a typo, its 'd-none',

Comment: Please see [mcve] - emphasis on *complete*.   How is `incidentChangeHandler` called?  It's not in your Razor code.  What's the *actual* value of `selectedValue` (not what it should be, we can see what it does if ==3 but we're doubting it does ==3.  Equally we can see you have an alert, but you've not stated if that alert is called.  Please include all relevant *rendered* html (testDiv and the select)

Comment: yes that alert is called when selected value is 3, i will provide reproducible example

Comment: So it's down to what `#testDiv` is and whether you have the class `d-none` defined (and as what).  Getting there.